IPv6 without Link-Local using Unique Local Addresses only?
I haven't seen any discussion online about this, but after some testing I have some questions.
Here's a quick overview of my testing environment, meant to replicate production infrastructure only at this point (Preparing for an IPv6 migration in a year).
All servers are manually assigned a Unique Local Address. Each existing IPv4 Subnet will be converted over to using a /120 IPv6 (I know I don't need to conserve, but the addresses are shorter to type).
The internet gateway conducts NAT66. I chose this because public IPv6 blocks are not given to a network for life, so might as well make the internet gateway the one to manage them. And to add IPv4 compability, will be implementing DNS64 and NAT64 at the gateway as well.
I have no need for any autoconfigration of any type (except neighbor discovery) since this is infrastructure that is static. So throw SLAAC, DHCPv6, and RA out the window.
I was testing some IPsec communication between hosts in the test network (two Debian servers on the same lan segment), and got annoyed at seeing Link-Local addresses in packet captures, so I just went in to each server and deleted their link-locals.
Coming from IPv4, I didn't think anything was wrong with this, as who cares about APIPA, right?
Well, after skimming through RFC 4291, I saw this:
   Link-Local addresses are designed to be used for addressing on a
   single link for purposes such as automatic address configuration,
   neighbor discovery, or when no routers are present.

Which I thought was weird, because my two test servers that only had Unique Local Addresses were conducting neighbor discovery just fine, I had seen it in the packet captures.
So now I am confused, partly because of how I plan to implement IPv6 (unique local on all devices, nat one to one for public ipv6 at gateway).
Why are link-local addresses needed at all in a static environment? It would appear unique local addresses handle neighbor discovery just fine.
And if they are not needed, why does Linux have no way of disabling the automatic generation of these addresses when an interface comes up? (Theres no sysctl var for disabling that feature, seems heavily baked into the kernel at this point)
Heres a pic of the packet capture of the no link-local ND:

Quick-edit:
I meant NPTv6 not NAT66.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You seem to want to apply IPv4 thinking to IPv6, and that can lead to big problems in the future, even if it seems to work today.
Using NAT (NPTv6 is an "Experimental" RFC, not a "_Standards Track" RFC) with IPv6 can cause problems with things like VoIP, IPSec, etc. because the original IPv6 addresses embedded in the data do not get translated, and it will not match what is on the IPv6 header. There are ugly workarounds for IPv4, such as SIP-ALG fixes that look inside VoIP packets to translate the IP addressing in the data.
Also, remember that NDP is not only for discovering hosts on the same network. It is also used for RAs. A router will put its link-local address on the RAs, such that every network advertised on a link uses the same gateway address (the router link-local address) for the router of the network.
Every IPv6 interface will have a link-local address in the link-local fe80::/64.
I have seen where people also want to disable or restrict multicast on an IPv6 network, but IPv6 makes heavy use of multicast, and it is required for NDP.
In any case, IPv6 link-local addressing costs you nothing, and you can just ignore it if you do not want to use it. There is no advantage to stop using it, and there are plenty of downsides because every IPv6 implementation expects it, and not having it can cause hard to diagnose problems. There are OSes, tools, and applications that can expect link-local addressing that will not properly work without it.
You can, of course, set your network up the way you want, but trying to buck the standards can create problems for you later.

As much as I disagree with how IPv6 was designed, I cannot disagree with the current state of technology using IPv6. Breaking software that needs link local is a valid reason to keep link local addresses.
